# python xml filter based on multiple conditions on different nodes

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, xml.etree

I have the following xml data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
  <Employee1>
      <FirstName>Tanmay</FirstName>
      <LastName>Patil</LastName>
      <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
      <Email>tanmaypatil@xyz.com</Email>
      <Address>
           <City>Bangalore</City>
      </Address>
      <name> XXXXX</name>
  </Employee1>
    <Employee2>
      <FirstName>Tanmay</FirstName>
      <LastName>Patil</LastName>
      <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
      <Email>tanmaypatil@xyz.com</Email>
      <Address>
           <City>Chennai</City>
      </Address>
      <name> YYYYYY</name>
  </Employee2>
    <Employee3>
      <FirstName>Tanmay</FirstName>
      <LastName>Patil</LastName>
      <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
      <Email>tanmaypatil@xyz.com</Email>
      <Address>
           <City>Bangalore</City>
      </Address>
      <name> ZZZZZ</name>
  </Employee3>
</Company>
```

I want to filter based on, City = Bangalore and get relevant contents of name tags for each.

The desired output when filtered City = Bangalore:

```
        <name> XXXXX</name>
        <name> ZZZZZ</name>
```

I have tried using the below and nothing helped me:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
tree.findall('city=Bangalore').name
```

But did not get what I am trying.  Can someone help please?

Comment: Can you use lxml instead of ElementTree?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use XPath:

```
'//Employee[Address/City="Bangalore"]/name'
```

Comment: thanks. can u please elaborate what will be full command to do this? In the light of dynamic tags?

Comment: @Shiva I'm not sure since I don't use `ETree`, but try something like `[element.text for element in tree.findall('//Employee[Address/City="Bangalore"]/name')]`. [How to use XPath in `ETree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath)

Comment: @Shiva also what do you mean by *'dynamic tags'*?

Comment: I meant dynamic tags, <Employee1>,<Employee2>,<Employee3> etc

Comment: @Shiva then try `'//Address[City="Bangalore"]/following-sibling::name'`. Also instead of `//Employee` you can try `//*[starts-with(name(), "Employee")]`: `'//*[starts-with(name(), "Employee") and Address/City="Bangalore"]/name')]`

Comment: `starts-with` works with lxml, but the OP uses the standard ElementTree module.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem like you but used minidom. I wrote two small functions to solve it. I wrote a some Code based on your original xml. This gives a list with all nodes containing Bangalore.

```
from xml.dom import minidom

def findChild(parent, childLocalName):
    for child in parent._get_childNodes():
        if child._get_localName() == childLocalName:
            return True, child
    return False, child

def followXMLPath(parent, path):# path should be a list of node names as string
    if path != None:
        for localName in path:
            result = findChild(parent, localName)
            if result[0] == True:
                parent = result[1]
            else:
                return result[0], parent
        return result
    else:
        return "error", parent

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xml = "C:\\Users\\AJ2MSGR\\Downloads\\bangalor.txt"
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(xml)
    finds = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Employee')

    bangaloreEmployees = []
    for element in finds:
        searchResult = followXMLPath(element,["Address", "City"]) #gives back a tuple
        success = searchResult[0]
        cityNode = searchResult[1]
        if success :
            if cityNode.firstChild.data == "Bangalore":
                bangaloreEmployees.append(element)
        else:
            print("nope")

    for element in bangaloreEmployees:
        print("::")
        print(findChild(element,"ContactNo")[1].firstChild.data)
        print(findChild(element,"name")[1].firstChild.data)
```